# tvOS pressesBegan() not updating in GameScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my GameScene, when I update variables using 'touchesBegan()' it works fine, but when I pass 'pressesBegan()' from the GameViewController to the GameScene, the code gets excited, but the changes get ignored.

GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        scene?.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
    }
```

GameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var test = true
    ...
    override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        test = false
        print(test)
    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        print(test)
    }
}
```

This code will result in "false" then "true" in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call pressesBegan, you are creating a new Gamescene,  you need to do

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    if let skView = self.view as? SKView
    {
        skView.scene?.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```